# Use log to solve $\int a^{-bx} dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms

we were given this integral in class

$\int a^{-bx} dx$

the solution of this integral is $\frac{-1}{b\ln a}(a^{-bx})$

then our professor asked, could this integral be solved using log instead of ln?

most of the times i use the properties of the exponential function and the natural logarithm to make this statement in the beginning:
$e^{\ln a}=a$, and so on

giving the question my professor asked i started to think that maybe we could use log instead of ln. i tried to use this statement: $\log{10^{a}}=a$, but then i got confused on how i should process this form. i always found myself go back to use the properties of the exponential function and natural logarithm no matter how many times i tried to look at different perspectives.

my desp*rated self think to just replaced ln with log in the final solution but i really doubt that's the right answer.

any answer or hint will be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Might want to look up the change of base for logarithms

Answer (score 0):

Since$$a^{-bx}=e^{-bx\ln(a)}=e^{-bx\log(a)/\log(e)},$$you have$$\int a^{-bx}\,\mathrm dx=-\frac{b\log(e)}{\log(a)}e^{-bx\log(a)/\log(e)}=-\frac{b\log(e)}{\log(a)}a^{-bx}.$$

Comment: Constant of integration missing.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That is insubstantial to the question.